# 'Unknown C global variable' error when generating Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, swig, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to generate documentation for a python project. I have about 6 different packages; 5 of them work fine but whenever I try to generate documentation for the 6th I get the following error message:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 1066, in can_document_member
    return isinstance(member, class_types) and \
NameError: Unknown C global variable
```

The Sphinx error log:

```
# Sphinx version: 1.1.3
# Python version: 3.3.2
# Docutils version: 0.11 release
# Jinja2 version: 2.7.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 189, in main
    app.build(force_all, filenames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 204, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 196, in build_update
    'out of date' % len(to_build))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 216, in build
    purple, length):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 120, in status_iterator
    for item in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/environment.py", line 613, in update_generator
    self.read_doc(docname, app=app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/environment.py", line 761, in read_doc
    pub.publish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/core.py", line 217, in publish
    self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/readers/__init__.py", line 72, in read
    self.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/readers/__init__.py", line 78, in parse
    self.parser.parse(self.input, document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/__init__.py", line 172, in parse
    self.statemachine.run(inputlines, document, inliner=self.inliner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 170, in run
    input_source=document['source'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/statemachine.py", line 239, in run
    context, state, transitions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line
    return method(match, context, next_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2726, in underline
    self.section(title, source, style, lineno - 1, messages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 327, in section
    self.new_subsection(title, lineno, messages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 395, in new_subsection
    node=section_node, match_titles=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 282, in nested_parse
    node=node, match_titles=match_titles)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 195, in run
    results = StateMachineWS.run(self, input_lines, input_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/statemachine.py", line 239, in run
    context, state, transitions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line
    return method(match, context, next_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2726, in underline
    self.section(title, source, style, lineno - 1, messages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 327, in section
    self.new_subsection(title, lineno, messages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 395, in new_subsection
    node=section_node, match_titles=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 282, in nested_parse
    node=node, match_titles=match_titles)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 195, in run
    results = StateMachineWS.run(self, input_lines, input_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/statemachine.py", line 239, in run
    context, state, transitions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line
    return method(match, context, next_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2299, in explicit_markup
    nodelist, blank_finish = self.explicit_construct(match)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2311, in explicit_construct
    return method(self, expmatch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2054, in directive
    directive_class, match, type_name, option_presets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 2103, in run_directive
    result = directive_instance.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 1303, in run
    documenter.generate(more_content=self.content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 734, in generate
    self.document_members(all_members)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 629, in document_members
    classes = [cls for cls in AutoDirective._registry.values()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 630, in <listcomp>
    if cls.can_document_member(member, mname, isattr, self)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 1066, in can_document_member
    return isinstance(member, class_types) and \
NameError: Unknown C global variable
```

I can't see any clear differences between the one problematic package and the ones that work fine, and the Sphinx error doesn't seem to point at any particular problematic part of my stuff. Anybody know what could cause this?

**UPDATE**
 mzjn below seemed to hit it but the error is a bit convoluted. I was using SWIG, and for some reason wildcard import statements from other modules, i.e.

```
from foo import *
```

cause Sphinx to crash when foo imports something from a SWIG-generated module. However, if I go through and replace with specific import statements

```
from foo import bar
```

where bar is the class I actually need from foo, then everything works.

Comment: Is SWIG involved? "Unknown C global variable" can be found in the SWIG source code: https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Lib/python/pyinit.swg.

Comment: SWIG 1.1.1 is quite outdated. If I understand correctly there are two major branches: 1.3 and 2.0.x. The later branch dropped support of documentation, so one will have to add it in semi-automatic mode. You can see such implementation in CMU pocketsphinx project.